# Pyinstaller adding directory inside dist as data

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm facing this issue while building a executable of my [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5) application.
I've images folder which contain 6 images and I want to add this images directory in dist folder so structure will look like this ***`dist > app > images`*** but I'm not able to do that it copies all images instead of picking folder.

I've tried adding like this in `datas` list eg. `('images','images')` & `('images/*','images/*')`

Here is my **`app.spec`** look like

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['ui.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('logo.png', '.'), ('images', 'images')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='myapp',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='MyApplication',
)
```

I've run this command to update data

```
pyinstaller app.spec
```

What I'm missing let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange! updating `app.spec` file and running

```
pyinstaller app.spec
```

did not worked for me I don't know why If anyone know please let me know. What I did I deleted `dist`, `build` and old `app.spec` file and ran this command and it worked

```
pyinstaller ui.py -n myapp --add-data "images:images" --add-data "logo.png:."
```

Comment: on linux indeed you use a `:`  separator; on window it is `;`!

Comment: Hello @karelv I've already used `:` for linux.

Comment: Clear, I just wanted to share that on windows it is `;`! (`:` didn't work on my system)